# Why was my question closed *after* it was deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Umm, recently joined Hardware Recommendations; posted a [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14469/what-batteries-are-compatible-for-hp-pavillion-gaming-cx-0xxx-series-of-laptops), which got deleted by a [mod](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8/artofcode) (without specifying reason). I [flagged](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/16933) it for attention, after which the reason was mentioned as "off-topic", and the question was closed, and rightly so. But it seems, the mod forgot to undelete it. Is it a good idea to flag it for undeletion? Because I frankly don't find deleted questions being marked closed and kept deleted helpful. If these questions are closed *instead* of deletion, we at least have examples of 'off-topic' posts that are already present, which will prevent others from asking similar ones.

Answer (score 2):

It's site policy on Hardware Recommendations to both close *and* delete off-topic posts to help avoid the impression that off-topic posts are okay here; this is part of the strict quality requirements that were a precondition from SE to setting up this site.

Comment: Umm... How can deleting *or* closing mean anything otherwise?